# Save Settings in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, save, settings

I am trying to save certain Settings (checkBoxes that are checked by the User, Urls that are changed etc.) to my local Computer, so that the Default Settings basically become the User modified once.
I've found that in Visual Studio this can be done easily using a Settings file ([Settings C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))
but my question is, since i have more than just one field that Needs to be saved, should i create more than one Settings file (one for each Checkbox - which would be ridiculously many) or can i save everything in one.
A thorough Explanation would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: That page shows exactly how you should do, but yes you shouldn't use one file for each field.

Comment: Also note that if your settings are fairly complicated, you can wrap them in a custom class and use that with the Settings file, [as explained here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CustomAppSettings.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use single User Settings file with multiple key-value pairs (make sure to use a proper `bool` type for this particular case).

Answer (score 1):

No, Settings file is key-value file and you must store all your settings in single file.